# JS, event emitter, callback and asynchrony

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a library written on the callback pattern ...

I want to log in, check errors and continue next, but a misunderstanding of the js asynchronous operation does not give me that ...

```
let errorInfo = [];

function login() {
    ....
    client.logOn(logOnOptions);

    client.on('error', function (e) { // here callback to check for errors during auth, if it is not handle, the application will throw an exception
        errorInfo.push(e.message);
    })

nextFunction();
}
```

In this case, if there is an error, JS will start executing the next function nextFunction(), with an empty array ...

How can I stop the transition to the next function until the auth check passes?

Comment: Should be some *success* event you could use to know when it completes successfully, and then you could use `nextFunction()` in success callback

Comment: It's going to execute `nextFunction` immediately. There *might* be an error **later on**. The error won't happen before `nextFunction` is called.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine, I want to wait for filling the array if there are errors and continue

Comment: Looks like a good use case for using promises

Comment: @charlietfl, could you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Not enough shown to know how `logOn` works. Read up on how to use promises

Comment: @charlietfl, i try but callback "function(e)" handle when there is an error